# I'm resizing an Image via PILLOW on my flask backend, but when it gets to the line of code .resize, it fails?

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize an uploaded file. So far I am confident that the image is loaded properly, and the PILLOW image class is created. It runs through my resizing script, but then it always stops on the .resize code...

I run the code on my desktop (not on a server), and the image resize works, but when I combine the resizing script with an image uploaded via POST, it's not working and shows a 500 error. What's going on?

I used `print imageThumbnail.size` right after the imageresizer code and got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'`

```
def imageResizer(im, pixellimit):

  width, height = im.size

  if width > height:
    #Land scape mode. Scale to width.

    aspectRatio = float(height)/float(width)
    Scaledwidth = pixellimit
    Scaledheight = int(round(Scaledwidth * aspectRatio))
    newSize = (Scaledwidth, Scaledheight)
  elif height > width:
    #Portrait mode, Scale to height.
    aspectRatio = float(width)/float(height)
    Scaledheight = pixellimit
    Scaledwidth = int(round(Scaledheight * aspectRatio))
    newSize = (Scaledwidth, Scaledheight)

  #FAILS RIGHT HERE... I double checked by writing print flags all over, and it so happens nothing past this line gets written
  imageThumbnail = im.resize(newSize)

  return imageThumbnail
```

Here's the portion of the FLask framework.

```
file = request.files['file']
    location = str(args['lat']) + str(args['lon'])
    location = location.replace('.','_')
    GUID = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + location
    datetimeEntry = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    fullFileName = GUID + '.' + file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
      filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

      image = Image.open(file)
      imageThumbnail = imageResizer(image, 800)
      #NOTHING PAST THIS POINT GETS EXECUTED
      imageThumbnailName = GUID + "thumb" + '.' + file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
      imageThumbnailName.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], imageThumbnailName))
      file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_LARGE_IMAGES'], fullFileName))
```

Comment: BTW, your first three lines could be replaced with `width, height = im.size`

Comment: In your view you define a variable named `image`, but you pass a variable named `im` to `imageResizer`. Was this just a typo when posting or is that what the code actually looks like?

Comment: @dim Dang, I thought I found it there, but that's just a typo. They're all im in my code... I think if the name was off, the error would have been different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to open:

`file = request.files['file']
image = Image.open(file)`

That `file` is not an actual file, but some metadata object with upload information. What you should do instead is:

`image = Image.open(file.stream)`